# Java: How to get File.listOfFiles working non-recursively on linux?

Tags: java, linux, file, recursion

I use this piece of code to find XML files that another part of my program creates in a given directory:

```
String fileName;
File folder = new File(mainController.XML_FILES_LOCATION);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
        if (fileName.endsWith(".xml")) {
            Document readFile = readFoundXmlFile(fileName);
            if (readFile != null) {
                boolean postWasSuccesful = mainController.sendXmlFile(readFile, fileName);
                reproduceXmlFile(readFile, fileName, postWasSuccesful);
                deleteXmlFile(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is that it reads every XML file that gets placed in the given directory, it sends it to an URL and it copies it to a subdirectory (either 'sent' or 'failed' based on the boolean postWasSuccedful) and deletes the original so it won't be sent again.

In Windows this works as expected, but I've transferred the working code to a Linux machine and all of a sudden it get's in this loop of sending bla.xml and a second later sent\bla.xml and again a second later sent\sent\bla.xml followed by sent\sent\sent\bla.xml, etc.

Why is Linux deciding for itself that listFiles() is recursive?? And, better, how to prevent that? I can add an extra check in the if-statement looking for files ending with .xml that there isn't a directory-char allowed in the fileName, but that's a workaround I don't want as the amount of files in the pick-up directory will never be high whereas the amount of files in the sent subdirectory can get quite high after a while and I wouldn't want this piece of code to become slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that `reproduceXmlFile()` builds the target pathname using a hard-coded backslash (`"\"`), and therefore you're actually creating files with backslashes in their names.

You need to use `File.separator` rather than that hard-coded `"\"`.  Or use something like `new File("sent", fileName).toString()` to generate your output pathnames.

(Apologies if I'm wrong!)

Comment: Your psychic powers are truly powerful. BTW, I do not know any reason to actually use \ anywhere, the / works fine in windows ....